# GeoPoint equivalent for a Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have fields `x` and `y` on some search documents that correspond to Cartesian coordinates, and I'd like to perform a radial search like:

```
query = '(x * x) + (y * y) < 100'
```

which would equate to "find all the things less than 10m away from (0,0)"

Trying to use that *particular* expression fails with `QueryError: Failed to parse query`, so it seems I need to take another approach.

**Is there a built-in way to do this?**

I've seen the GeoPoint fields and `distance` query function that nearly do what I need, the problem being that my `x,y`s aren't longitude and latitude. I've thought about trying to abuse this - map all coordinates to a much smaller domain, in which the lat/long system closely approximates the Cartesian domain. This seems a little hacky though, so I'm looking for something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there isn't.**

The search API doesn't support arbitrarily computed expressions on fields (like `x * x` in your example). What it does support is enumerated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings). Your mapping from Cartesian coordinates to lat/long fields sounds like it would be the most plausible approach.

(Full disclosure: I'm on the team.)

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that was the case. Appreciate you clarifying for me.

Comment: You're quite welcome! I'm sorry that we don't offer better support for your use case, at least right now.